# $setValidity in AngularJS not updating ctrl.$error

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

I'm sending an AJAX request to Node, which returns "true" if a field is not unique in the MongoDB database, i.e. an object has been found with that field and value, and "false" if no object was found. Here's the route callback:

```
exports.check = function(req, res) {
    var query = {};
    query[req.body.field] = req.body.value;
    console.log(query);

    Invoice.findOne(query, function(err, invoice) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            if (invoice) {
                res.send(true);
            } else {
                res.send(false);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

(Sidenote: please correct me if this is totally inappropriate use of `res.send` and let me know what I should use instead)

Here is the Angular directive:

```
app.directive('ngUnique', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '@',
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        elem.on('blur', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            var val = elem.val();

            var data = {
              'field': scope.ngModel,
              'value': val
            };

            $http.post('/invoices/check', data).then(function(res) {
              console.log(res.data);
              console.log(ctrl.$error);
              ctrl.$setValidity('exists', res.data);
              console.log(res.data);
              console.log(ctrl.$error);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

The console log output is bizarre (this is when I enter a previously used value, i.e. `res.data` should be `true`):

```
true  // res.data before ctrl.$setValidity
Object {}  // ctrl.$error before ctrl.$setValidity
true  // res.data again
Object {exists: false}  // ctrl.$error after ctrl.$setValidity('exists', res.data)
```

I can't understand why this is happening. I thought at first that $setValidity wasn't executing at all, but the log shows otherwise. Why, then, is it setting a different value? Am I missing something? Is it a scope problem?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Current version: 1.2.12

Answer (score 1):

The $error object is storing the inverse of the isValid argument passed to $setValidity. When calling $setValidity, you are passing in value of true. The $error object then stores the value of false against that key to indicate that there is no error.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1638